# Expectation subscripts before and after the brackets

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

In Bishop's "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning", Eq.(10.107) contains a term which reads
$E_\alpha[\ln q(\mathbf w)]_\mathbf w$.
Why does he use different positions for $\alpha$ and $\mathbf w$?

I'm familiar with the subscripts *before* the brackets, like $E_\alpha[\ln p(\alpha)]$, which means "taking the expectation using $p(\alpha)$", but I haven't seen a subscript *after* the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's all typos. The Eq (10.107) is
$$\begin{align}\mathcal{L}(q)&=\mathbb E_w[\ln p(w,\alpha,t)]-\mathbb E[\ln q(w,\alpha)]\\&=\mathbb E_w[\ln p(t|w)]+\mathbb E_{w,\alpha}[\ln p(w|\alpha)]+\mathbb E_\alpha[\ln p(\alpha)]-\mathbb E_\alpha[\ln q(w)]_w - \mathbb E[\ln q(\alpha)]\end{align}$$

The last two terms in the second line are apparently derived from $\mathbb E[\ln q(w,\alpha)]$, by substituting the Eq 10.91, i.e. $$q(w,\alpha)=q(w)q(\alpha)$$

So, the corrected last two terms should be $-\underbrace{\mathbb E_w[\ln q(w)]}_{E[\ln q(w)]}-\underbrace{E[\ln q(\alpha)]}_{E_\alpha[\ln q(\alpha)]}$.

If you also look at the other equations (10.108-112), all of them are written in $E[f(a)]_{a}$ which also signals typos.